# Use android phone as a server

Tags: android

First of all i am new to Android programming with no previous experience in server side programming. I am developing an app that works as a cashier for restaurants. The restaurant may have one device working as a cashier for take-away customers and one or more devices in every hall he has for indoor customers. Instead of having one local database for every device in the restaurant i need to have only one centralized database which every device can use.
Can i share only one copy of local databases to all other devices via api or so to achieve this??
If not what alternative options do i have since as i stated earlier i have no previous experience in setting up a server myself??

Comment: you can for sure. You probably will have to create an API for your server-device, but it is quite easy to find how to run an HTTP server on your device.

Comment: I would use an online datastore service like FireBase, or Azure, or an hosted MongoDB proved etc...

Comment: Personally I would use Firebase as it can offer a totally server-less architecture which is also your requirement, I suppose

Comment: Uploading and downloading every receipt the user makes to 'Firebase' will require costs as the app grows which i want to minimize at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended method:** Setup a server and create APIs to share and store data in your server's database.

**An other way to get around the problem:** You can use the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to store your data on cloud. In this way all of your devices can share a cloud database without having to setup a server.

Comment: "Use the cloud" is the simplest answer, however it has several disadvantages: you need experience to account common problems like data security and if your Internet is offline you can close your shop -> IMHO a cloud database is a bad idea, especially as Mostafa is not experienced.

Comment: I would use the "simplest" answer if he had some experience. Plus problems like data security are not much of an issue specially when using Firebase at this initial stage.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. Even with Firebase you can make everything wrong and expose all your data to everyone on the net. There are dozens of examples in the Play Store, using Firebase this way.

Comment: Thats why they have **rules** on Firebase.

Comment: Firebase will require a stable and permanent internet connection which can not be guaranteed. It also will require costs as the app grows.

Comment: For setting up a server i don't have any experience in this field at all. If it is the only solution may someone please refer me to a good tutorial to get started.

Comment: As you are developing for Android, and you already have some experience in JAVA, I would recommend you to learn Spring. For starters [check this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-spring-online-courses/answer/Alket-Cecaj)